# mysqli_fetch_array no esta trayendo la informacion

Tags: php, mysql

Buen dia, estoy haciendo una consulta para sacar los nombres de las tablas dentro de una base de datos. Cuando escribo el query en php my admin funciona, es decir salen los nombres de las tablas. Al momento de correr el archivo php lo que se imprime en pantalla es el mensaje de error dentro del else, es decir, al parecer la funcion `msqli_query()` no se esta ejecutando correctamente. ¿Que puede estar fallando? Aca les dejo el codigo:

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","miBDD");
    $consulta = "
                USE miBDD;
                SHOW TABLES;
                ";
    if(mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta)){
        $tablas = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);
        print_r($tablas);
    }
    else{
        echo 'error';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta cambiando tu variable consulta por esto: 
$consulta = "SHOW TABLES FROM miBDD";
Ya que estas haciendo mal la consulta, no es lo mismo hacerla en php a php myadmin. Saludos.

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","miBDD");
    $consulta = "SHOW  TABLES FROM miBDD";
    $query_consulta=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
    if($query_consulta){
        while ($tabla = mysqli_fetch_row($query_consulta)) {
            echo "Tabla: {$tabla[0]}<br>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'error';
    }
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

**EDIT:** lo que estas haciendo es mandar un string como parámetro a la función: 'mysqli_fetch_array', por lo que necesitas guardar en una variable el resultado del query.
**EDIT 2:**agregue el while que sirve para imprimir los nombres de las tablas y agregue el cierre de conexión que de igual forma es siempre importante

Comment: Despues de cambiarlo me sale un error. ```mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in...```

Comment: Edite mi respuesta checala y si fue de ayuda no se te olvide marcarla como respuesta útil. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias ya me esta arrojando algo, solo que por algun motivo solo me arroja el valor dentro de la posicion 0 del arreglo.

Comment: para ver todo lo que te trae te recomiendo usar var_dump($tablas); ya que $tablas es un array y por ende lo tienes que recorrer.

Comment: Lo que me esta saliendo es esto, a pesar de que tengo 4 tablas guardadas. ```array (size=2)
  0 => string 'exa' (length=3)
  'Tables_in_capacitacion' => string 'exa' (length=3)```

Comment: todas tus tablas están en la misma base? ya que el resultado del var_dump es valido

Comment: si, de hecho, lo que intente es usar echos para cada indice del arreglo pero solo se crea uno solo.

Comment: Edite la respuesta acorde a lo que me mencionaste, agregue el while para imprimir lo que trae de la base y de igual forma añadí el cierre de conexión que hacia falta